# Same routing behavior on different nodes/routers

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I know, that if I use a consistent hashing group router, it will always rout to the same registered routees. 
So I wrote my application, with a few routees on there own `routee-nodes` and a `public-node` with a router, which is reachable by the client.
If the client sends a message it is routed as it should be and it works fine.
Now what I want to do is, add more `public-nodes` with thier own router that provides the same sending/routing behavior as every other `public-node`.
What I mean is, that it should not matter if a client sends message `XYZ` to `public-node` `A`, `B` or `C`. It should always go to the same `routee-node`.
At first I thought that akka may provides this behavior by default, because:

1. I used a `group` and not a `pool` router, so everyone knows the same routees
2. I leared that cluster nodes could be ordered

So I assumed that the routees list is ordered and the different routers map the same keys to the same routees. But testing showed me that I was wrong.

So, is there way in akka to achieve this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, this behavior shoud be the standart for consistent hashing group routers and it is a bug in the akka-cluster package (current version 2.3.0-RC1)
See [this tickt](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3853#/activity/ticket%3a) and [this google-group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/Kxr_CmebcQw) for more details.